# Host Protected Area: User Data Logs/Versions?

Tags: hard-drive, security, recovery

I recently sold a computer that had sensitive financial information stored on it. I stumbled across this article and I am now very worried:

https://www.easytechjunkie.com/what-is-a-host-protected-area.htm

Is the information on this website true? Does the HPA actually include a version of all of the files that have been stored on the HDD? Does it contain a log of files that have been stored?

I have heard conflicting information on this very website, stating that the HPA does not contain any logs or user data (unless it is deliberately placed there which is not my use-case).

Thank you!

Comment: “I recently sold a computer that had sensitive financial information stored on it.” Did you wipe the computer before selling it? If not, then why are you asking about this now? If the machine was properly wiped then there should be no worries. But if you just sold the machine without wiping, what do you expect to do now?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I reset the computer using the windows "completely clean the drive" option. I did this twice, several weeks apart. I know that the HPA is inaccessible to the OS. I'm wondering if there is any user data or user logs of files on the HPA.

Comment: Website doesn’t work. But I can tell by the title of the article, it’s one of those non-legitimate technical websites, that have fake articles with information that while might be accurate is also misleading. In this I suspect it will literally just be Wikipedia, if the other three fake websites with the exact same article title, is any indication. Since this protected area of the HDD, didn’t store your files, your files were realistically unrecoverable the moment you reinstalled Windows the first time. The linked website shouldn’t be trusted.

Comment: The linked website shouldn’t be trusted. It’s full of ads, it says absolutely nothing, while saying nothing in hundreds of words. It’s also completely false.

Comment: Sorry about the website not working. I clicked the link 3 times and it worked once.

The quote I am particularly interested in is this:

"There is one section that is reserved, called the host protected area, that stores a small version of everything that passes through it. This is like an advanced cache, except the information stays in the HPA much longer."

Is this true?

Comment: Cloudflare blocked it suggesting it was a host error not a device error, regardless, I used a VPN and it worked but the contents of the article is rubbish. It was even fact checked….give me a break….clearly an article that says a good amount without actually saying anything

Comment: Is it true that the HPA collects versions or logs of user data though?

Comment: Honestly? This looks like an AI-generated article.

Answer (score 1):

The Host Protected Area feature set, as defined in earlier ATA/ACS standards (it has been obsoleted by and removed from ACS-3) is a set of commands that allows the user to make a portion of the logical blocks on the drive that needs extra some operations before they can be accessed.

In other words, the feature is essentially to reserve spaces that are hidden for special purpose.

With that said, "special" here is not defined. How the space is used entirely depends on you, programs on you machine, and/or your machine.

FWIW, modern drives, especially but not limited to SSDs, may have "hidden reserved" space anyway, since the logical blocks may not necessarily be statically mapped to the same sectors / memory anyway, which may be a even more significant concern.

BTW, if you secure erased your with builtin special command of your drive (instead of overwriting it with usual programs that ultimately generate simple write commands), such as security erase or sanitize, you shouldn't need to worry about potential HPA set up, since they don't care about HPA. (However, they don't necessarily make sure sectors / memory behind the scene are at least zeroed out.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that the HPA collects versions or logs of user data though?

No. There is a *very tiny* grain of truth in there, but it's 99.9999% nonsense.

On its own the HPA is a passive function. It's called "Host Protected" because the *host* (i.e. the OS running on the computer) protects or unprotects the HPA on-demand, using specific ATA commands; by default the HPA is disabled until the OS or some program configures it, and when it's enabled the only thing it does is restrict access.

The mechanism is kind of like over-provisioning: you tell the disk to report fewer "Total sectors on disk" than it normally has, and the sectors are *cut off from normal usage* and become the HPA. By default, disks come with the HPA disabled (i.e. set to 0 sectors).

Now, some backup apps – Acronis, for example – have a function to *store periodic backups* in the HPA, so that most kinds of regular malware won't be able to access it (only the special Acronis driver can), and that might possibly be the source of the original claim of "storing everything", if you squint.

The rest of the article's claims don't really make much sense; e.g. the HPA has nothing to do with the system's boot process (except perhaps in very rare cases when an OEM decides to put the "system recovery" image there – I've seen old laptops that had a whole dedicated button for that).

(HDDs do have an inaccessible area called the "system area", but that is not the same thing as the HPA because it is inaccessible from the host as well – it is used to boot *the HDD itself;* that is, the HDD's firmware and calibration data is stored in its system area.)

Answer (score 0):

"Does the HPA actually include a version of all of the files that have been stored on the HDD?" Think about this question logically. How can it? It doesn't have infinite capacity. At most, HPA may record a filename and path, but not the contents of the file.

It's also not a given that a drive has a HPA, at all. Without recovering the PC to check, you'll never know.

Answer (score 0):

The article you cited seems to be cheap sensationalism.

The Wikipedia article
[Host protected area (HPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area)
lists many uses for the HPA (including rootkits), but none of them is
the registering of every (?) file that passed through the computer.

This part of the article you found is pure bullshit. Especially since
the Wikipedia article specifically says that the operating system
has no access to this area.

The only way such information could have been recorded in the HPA is
if your computer was infected by a rootkit that amused itself by
recording file-names. And even if that far-fetched theory was correct,
what information can be retrieved for these names, except perhaps the
identity of your bank.

A hacker of enough talent to infect your computer with a rootkit wouldn't
*need* to record file-names. Why do so when he already has full control
of your computer?

I think you can be confident that resetting the computer was enough to
protect your data from most users.

However, if you have only formatted the disk with quick format and have
not erased all the unallocated parts of the disk, they could still
contain fragments of your files, even if the file-table was erased.
These file-fragments could be recovered by freely-available software.
However, finding something useful among all this meaningless data would
be truly hard to do.